# Wiring problems on the TP4056 Module

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, wiring, circuit-protection, tp4056

I have been thinking of putting a 18650 Li-ion battery salvaged from an old laptop power battery to use so, I bought a few of those cheap TP4056 battery protection and charge circuit modules and I am a bit confused. I accidentally bridged the two B+ and OUT+ solder pads and now I am having a tough time removing the solder from them so I was wondering if I could directly connect the battery to the B+ and B- charging pads while the OUT+ is still connected to the B+. Will it be ok if I do so and will it affect the charging circuitry?

Comment: Does the module have a part number? I'm asking this because there are different types of 4056 modules: Some of them has DW01 supervisor IC, some of them does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason OUT+ and B+ are separated. There is a battery protection between OUT+ and B+. If you short it you effectively disable this protection, and that is definitely not a good thing. I wouldn't do it.